# mat-checkbox not updating correctly when dynamic values are set in Angular application

Tags: html, angular, typescript, checkbox, angular-material

I am using mat-checkbox in my Angular application to display a list of items with checkboxes. The values for the checkboxes are dynamic and are set using the **[value]** (or) **[checked]** input property of the mat-checkbox component.

However, I am facing an issue where the checkboxes are not updating correctly when the values are changed dynamically. Specifically, when I update the values, the checkboxes do not reflect the correct state and some of them are checked even though their value is set to false.

I have tried using **ngModel** to bind the values and also tried using **ChangeDetectorRef **to detect changes, but the issue persists.

Can someone help me understand what could be causing this issue and how I can fix it?

**Ts file:**

```
checkboxDefaultValuelang_6800898() {
         this.pickListValues[this.__yokihidden21$tableName]['lang'] = [{
             val: "eng",
             displayName: "yokihidden21.lang.Option.eng",
             isChecked: false
         }, {
             val: "tamil",
             displayName: "yokihidden21.lang.Option.tamil",
             isChecked: false
         }, {
             val: "hindi",
             displayName: "yokihidden21.lang.Option.hindi",
             isChecked: false
         }];
         this.conditionalFormatJson.pickListValues = this.pickListValues;
     }
```

**HTML file:**

```
<mat-form-field [floatLabel]="'always'" appearance="none" formGroupName="pfm67408" id="pfm67408_lang">
                                <section class="example-section">
                                    <mat-checkbox id="FLD_hid_entry21_WEB_Grid_yokihidden21_DUMMY$$lang_input_{{item.displayName | translate}}" *ngFor="let item of pickListValues[__yokihidden21$tableName]['lang']" [checked]="item.isChecked" (change)="onChangeCheckbox(pickListValues[__yokihidden21$tableName]['lang'], item, '', 'lang', dataObject['yokihidden21_DUMMY'],__yokihidden21$tableName,'lang$$yokihidden21');changeCallback('lang$$yokihidden21');">{{item.displayName | translate}}</mat-checkbox>
                                </section>
                                <mat-chip-list class="cs-mat-error">
                                    <mat-error><span *ngIf="!formGroup.get(__yokihidden21$tableName).get('lang').valid && !isValidFrom">Please select Lang</span></mat-error>
                                </mat-chip-list>
                            </mat-form-field>
```

I am using mat-checkbox in my Angular application to display a list of items with checkboxes. The values for the checkboxes are dynamic and are set using the **[value]** (or) **[checked]** input property of the mat-checkbox component.

```
Software version details:

    Angular: 13.3.9 
    Node: 14.18.3
    NPM: 6.14.15
    Ionic: 6.20.1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think use `*ngFor` directive on material checkbox it is not a good idea. Try to wrap checkbox in

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of pickListValues[__yokihidden21$tableName]['lang']">
  <mat-checkbox
 id="FLD_hid_entry21_WEB_Grid_yokihidden21_DUMMY$$lang_input_{{item.displayName | translate}}"  
      [checked]="item.isChecked
      (change)="onChangeCheckbox(pickListValues[__yokihidden21$tableName]['lang'], item, '', 'lang', dataObject['yokihidden21_DUMMY'],__yokihidden21$tableName,'lang$$yokihidden21');changeCallback('lang$$yokihidden21');">
      {{item.displayName | translate}}
   </mat-checkbox>
</ng-container>
```